# A alias remove local brach and create with same name again

Tags: bash, git, alias

I need to a alias remove local branch and regenerate with same name again. for example;

```sh
grb test-branch
```

> git regenerate branch

will make this automatically

```sh
 git branch -D test-branch && git checkout -b test-branch
```

how can I do this ?

is there any default shortcuts comes with vanilla git ?

Comment: There are lots of ways to make aliases (shell aliases, shell functions, and Git aliases are the three obvious ones here). For this particular case, though, consider using `git checkout -B test-branch` or `git switch -C test-branch`, which eliminates the need for the separate branch-delete step. Note that this will preserve the reflog for `test-branch`, which you might consider either good or bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the following function to your .bashrc or .zshrc file;

```sh
# git branch regenerate
function gbrr () {
    git branch -D "$@" && git checkout -b "$@"
}
```

And you can use it like below

```
gbrr feature/navbar
```